# trying to position a caption

Tags: css, position

please how will i position the(Click to Register now and place your orders) to stay in the middle between the reacheasy word on the left and the reach easy logo on he right below is my markup language(link to the page http://reacheasy.co.uk/testerid.php)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
     <title>Reacheasy - Foremost website for shopping from Uk, and globally to Nigeria</title>
   <meta name="description" content="We offer online shopping and shipping from UK stores to Nigeria" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="shipping to nigeria, freight to nigeria,online shopping from uk" />


    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<link href="reasy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>  
</head>
  <body>
<div id="outer">
<div id="page">
<div id="header">
<div id="adban" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -150px;">
<span style="left;"><a href="reregister.php">Click here to Register now and place your orders</a></span>
</div>
<div id="hlogo">
<span style="float:right;margin:2px 2px 0 0;"><img src="img/relogo2.jpg"  class="logoImage" width="96" height="96"/></span>
</div>
<span style="font-size:small;text-shadow: 10px 10px 1px grey;"><h1>Reacheasy<span style="font-size:small;"><?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></span></h1></span>
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="current"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="women.php">Women</a></li>
     <li><a href="men.php">Men</a></li>
     <li><a href="children.php">Children</a></li>
     <li><a href="homeandappliances.php">Home&amp;Appliances</a></li>
     <li><a href="visionandsound.php">Vision&amp;Sounds</a></li>
      <!--<li><a href="motoring.php">Motoring</a></li>-->
      <li><a href="homemore.php">More</a></li>
      <li><a href="howto.php">Help(How to?)</a></li>
  </ul>
</div> <!--end of navigation div -->
</div>
<div id="navigation">

<?php
if($_SESSION['username'])
{ ?>
<ul id="navigationlb">
<li><a href='howto.php'>Help(How to?)</a></li>
<li><a href='notification.php'>Consignment notification</a></li>
<li><a href='youraccount.php'>Order Placement</a></li>
<li><a href='relogout.php'>Log out</a></li>
 </ul>
<?php }else{
?>
  <div>
<form action='relogin.php' method='post' class='rl'>
<fieldset>
<legend>Login</legend>
    <div>
    <label for='username' class='fixedwidth'>Username</label>
    <input type='text' name='username' id='username'/>
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for='password' class='fixedwidth'>Password</label>
    <input type='password' name='password' id='password'/>
    </div>
<div class='buttonarea'>
    <input type='submit' value='Log in'/>
    </div>
<p>
<a href='reregister.php'>Register </a>
<BR>PLACE YOUR ORDERS FROM ANYWHERE</BR> 
IN THE WORLD </BR> TO NIGERIA
</p>
<!--<p>
<BR>PLACE YOUR ORDER FROM ANYWHERE</BR> 
IN THE WORLD </BR> TO NIGERIA
</p>-->
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some CSS styling to your `adban` element, something like this should do the trick:

```
<div id="adban" style="position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -150px;">
```

Comment: @Pankaj Sorry I don't understand your question

Comment: this css is already applied on that div. what you have suggested in your answer?

Comment: I don't see in http://reacheasy.co.uk/testerid.php any reference to the HTML provided. `reasy.css` is included using a relative URL so I don't have access to it. All I did was to add the HTML provided to position the element as requested.

Comment: I appreciate this but I found the same thing with the help of firebug, he applied inline css on that div if you view source it you will come to know.. by the way your answer will put him in the same condition as he is now..:) he want caption in middle between both logo.

Comment: @lostty84 are you sure it worked,@Mathieu I dont know how he solved this let it be :).

Comment: @pankaj I might be mistaken but don't you think he used my answer?

Comment: hahah That's strange I dont know how he got the solution applying same thing again. anyways problem should be solved and you solved it mysteriously :D :)

Comment: @Pankaj i simply applied the  mathieu css to the div, i have edited the script with the new one,check it

Comment: No hard feelings @lostty84 I don't know whats happening here.

Comment: @Pankaj please do you why this color is nor applying <p>
<a href='reregister.php'>Register </a>
<span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-color:#5CB3FF;"><BR>PLACE YOUR ORDERS FROM ANYWHERE</BR> 
IN THE WORLD </BR> TO NIGERIA</span>
</p>

Comment: just use color instead font-color, it should be like this "font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#5CB3FF;"

Answer (score 0):

Just apply

`top:50%` in your adban div

```
<div id="adban" style="margin-left:-150px; position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%;">
```